# Laravel Mocking Repository Controller - Method "all" from Mockery\Interface should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times

Tags: php, laravel, mocking

I'm mocking a Repository inside the controller, but when I call `CompanyController@index` (which in turn calls `CompanyRepository@all`), tests returns this error:

> Test\Unit\Shared\Repositories\CompanyRepositoryTest::test_all
>   Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method all() from Mockery_0__App_Shared_Repostiries_CompanyRepository should be called
>    exactly 1 time but called 0 times.

```php
<?php

namespace Test\Unit\Shared\Repositories;

use Mockery;
use Tests\TestCase;

class CompanyRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{

    protected $companyRepo;
    protected $company;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * @group mockingrepo3
     */
    public function test_all()
    {

        $this->companyRepo = Mockery::mock('\App\Shared\Repositories\CompanyRepository');
        $this->companyRepo->shouldReceive('all')
            ->andReturn(new \Illuminate\Support\Collection)
            ->once();

        $this->company = \App\Models\Company::find(3);
        $this->be($this->company);


        $this->app->instance('\App\Shared\Repositories\CompanyRepository', $this->companyRepo);

        $response = $this->call('GET', route('app.admin.company.index'));

        // $this->assertEquals(new \Illuminate\Support\Collection, $companies);
    }
}
```

**CompanyController**

```php
<?php

class CompanyController extends Controller
{

    private $companyRepo;

    public function __construct(CompanyRepository $companyRepo)
    {
        $this->companyRepo = $companyRepo;
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $companies = $this->companyRepo->all();
        return view("admin.company.index")->with(['companies' => $companies]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a possible typo in the Mocking namespace `Repostiries`.

Comment: In fact it was there but i'm getting same error..